# two mysql database to just one JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, mysqli

I have the following case.
I have two tables in the database.

posts and comments ...

I want to generate a `JSON` file with `PHP` that shows up the all the posts with their comments...

here is the structure of the two table just to give you a better vision:

**posts** table:

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p_body` text NOT NULL,
  `p_author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p_likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `post`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`);
```

**comments** table:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_body` text NOT NULL,
  `c_author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `c_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `comments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`);
```

This is the view of the `JSON` file I want to do

```
[
  {
    "title": "Post One",
    "body": [
      "text text text"
    ],
    "author": "Nick Moreton",
    "comments": [
      {
        "body": "This is my first comment",
        "author": "alex"
      },{
        "body": "Second comment,etc...",
        "author": "ali"
      }
    ],
    "likes": 200,
    "image": "http://placekitten.com/g/2000/600",
    "createdOn": 1408547127216
  }

... ]
```

I looked for a solution to this problem a lot and did not find what I wanted

Best Regards

### EDIT:

I want to make a loop inside a loop

The first loop is: posts

Inside posts loop is the comments loop

Comment: What is your actual question? Certainly you will not find an _exact_ solution to your task somewhere to just copy it. But you definitely can find endless examples that demonstrate how to use MySQL and PHP to generate a JSON serialized string from data read from a database. So what is your actual question?

Comment: I found solutions and examples but did not work with the same idea
 @arkascha

Comment: And what do you mean by that? What idea? What did not work?

Comment: Please note that we are here to help each other with our tasks. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. We expect you to do your own research, to learn and try yourself. To make a reasonable effort, not just to claim something does not work. If you are looking for someone to do your work for you then we suggest you hire a payed programmer...

Comment: Sorry, I have modified the question

Comment: Maybe I didn't look closely enough, but did you post your code attempt in with your question?

Comment: Write a SQL `JOIN` between the tables. Loop through the results and when the post ID is the same as a previous one, add the comment to its `comments` array, otherwise create a new element in the main result array.